# Why does 'ls' command in linux return some results in [squarebrackets].jar?

Tags: linux, tomcat, shell

Below is an example output of what I see when I run the 'ls' command on some directories in linux (this is from a tomcat/common/lib directory).

However I'm not clear on why some of the filenames are appearing inside [square brackets]

If someone could clarify this for me it would be much appreciated!

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1038825 Aug 30  2006 [ant].jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   566376 Apr  1  2008 [commons-collections].jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   107392 Aug 18  2006 [commons-dbcp].jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   114374 Aug 17  2006 [commons-el].jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   114374 Aug 17  2006 commons-el.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    25913 Aug 10  2006 [commons-logging-api].jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   112331 Jun 21  2007 commons-modeler.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    59695 Sep 26  2006 [commons-pool].jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1201 Jul 22  2009 etag-support.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    47008 Aug 18  2006 [jaf].jar
```

Comment: Because the filenames have square brackets in them.

Comment: Really? Why would that be? And why would there be, for example, [commons-el].jar and commons-el.jar in the same directory?

Comment: I don't know, which is why I didn't put it as an answer.

Comment: Because somebody put them both there.

Comment: Okay, but if someone has a suggestion such as 'in tomcat(/linux) this normally happens because of xxx' then that would be really helpful. Or if it just seems like 'god knows why that happened /why someone named the files like that and placed them there' then I guess it'd be useful to hear too

Comment: If you're an admin; obviously someone else has root privilages. If you don't know who made those files with square brackets, then you've got bigger problems than just oddly named files.

Comment: Tomcat seems to do that from RPM installs on redhat. I have no idea why it likes to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Because the filenames have square brackets in them - just like the comment from Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams says.

You may find that someone has been copying these files and used square brackets as a kind of special marker. Find out who wrote them and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

"Tomcat seems to do that from RPM installs on redhat. I have no idea why it likes to do that" - Resorath.

This is the conclusion I have now come to also.

Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: ​Which R​P​M​?​